# Getting the full sourcecode of a page with an output in javascript

Tags: php, web-scraping, curl

i would like to parse the number of the number of the snapshots of the website archive.org for a selected domain.
I see  that the number of snapshots is dynamical generated and is not visible in the source code.
For example in the url

[[`https://web.archive.org/web/20240000000000*/https://www.google.com]([`https://web.archive.org/web/20240000000000*/https://www.google.com)
i see once the page is loaded 'Saved 16.809.458 times' .
Is there a way to get the value of the number of the snapchots with cURL in PHP?

echo file_get_contents('https://web.archive.org/web/20240000000000*/https://www.google.com');

Comment: Try with a headless browser

Comment: If your question is specific to that site, they have an API that might be worth investigating: https://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php

Comment: Hi Chris Haas, i know but there is a limit on the usage.

Comment: @daniele you might find that they also block you if they find you doing excessive scraping of pages, too.

Comment: Adyson thank you but i wait 2 seconds for each request. Do you know a free api service that offer a headless browser?

Comment: @daniele A headless browser isn't tied to an API service. You'd only need a headless browser to try and scrape pages which use JavaScript to display things. If the site you want to scrape has an API, it will not involve JavaScript and you could use any HTTP client to interact with it.

Comment: If you want to find a headless browser that you can use with PHP, [look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+headless+browser). I can't recommend any specific product.

Comment: `thank you but i wait 2 seconds for each request`...well that's a good idea, but it gives no guarantees. Every site may have different rate limits or different rules. Or they have have techniques which detect bots and block them regardless. All you can do is try it out.

Comment: `but there is a limit on the usage`...don't you think that seems fair? You are using their server resources and their content, but they are getting nothing for it. If you automate your requests, there's a high chance it will consume far more of their processing resources than a human could in the same amount of time. And many sites rely on adverts to generate income - if you view their pages using a scraping tool, or only use their API, then they don't get any money, unless they charge for API access. So limiting your usage seems entirely reasonable in that context, don't you think?

Comment: ADyson i agree with you , but please note that i am doing an http request every 2 or 5 seconds and only for few days, i am not interested to scrape the entire archive.org

Comment: They don't know that when your requests start coming through though, do they. And that might still be several days worth of usage that could have generated income if they had been pages displayed in a browser rather than downloaded by a script. Anyway you'll have to try it, it might be fine or they might block you. In the absence of a published policy you can only try it and see what happens.